# Getting a web based InfoPath form on a custom aspx site

Tags: infopath, aspx

May I know if it is possible to put a web based infopath 2007 form on a custom ASPX file in a SharePoint 2007 Site? (The InfoPath 2007 form will appear inside a custom ASPX file.)

Comment: Was not the reply answered your question, I am curious?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the XmlFormView asp.net control to rendering the InfoPath form in SharePoint custom page,

Check this post from msdn,

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms778201.aspx

Or check these blogs with step by step snapshot

http://www.innovation-hut.com/go.aspx?ID=9e296cf2-4a17-43d9-8f1e-5fc9f93df3ce

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/infopath/archive/2006/10/21/hosting-infopath-forms-in-a-custom-aspx-page.aspx

Comment: +1 Hmmm, the question is twice upvoted and the answer not?!